# Can I use pure SQL in ASP.net MVC?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database, linq-to-sql

hello guys i need to use pure SQL queries for my database project 
at the same time i wanna use ASP.net MVC so i can learn a new technology !!! 
can i use SQL with ASP.net MVC WITHOUT using " LINQ to SQL " ?!
i'm still learning so i'm sorry if it so stupid using things the OLD SCHOOL 
but my instructor insists that he want to see a PURE SQL Queries

Comment: the amount of help you get does not correspond to how many capital letters and exclamation marks you use. There is an inverse correlation, if any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. You can use whatever you want for your model layer. Note, you can use raw SQL queries with LINQ To SQL as well.

```
Northwnd db = new Northwnd(@"c:\northwnd.mdf");
IEnumerable<Customer> results = db.ExecuteQuery<Customer>
(@"SELECT c1.custid as CustomerID, c2.custName as ContactName
    FROM customer1 as c1, customer2 as c2
    WHERE c1.custid = c2.custid"
);
```

Or perhaps your instructor wants straight up ADO.NET, which works fine too.
There is an [example here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Database-ADO.net/illustrateshowtoperformaSELECTstatementusingADONET.htm).

Comment: can you explain how can i do it in a simple matter. i've been searching for a long time :S

Comment: Are you asking how to use ADO.Net?

Comment: i want a RAW SQL as you said !!

Comment: @iyad: Please clarify your request. If you just want to execute SQL statements, you can use your database platform without using ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: No No i want to do the whole website using ASP.net " its not required using the .NET MVC " but for learning purposes. but i should submit the SQL queries as well . that's why i dont wanna use the ADO.NET " creating the model and using the methods ... i'm really sorry if my request is not clear , but i'm new to those stuff

Comment: @iyad: Ok, here is the first thing for you to learn: SQL queries cannot be executed and have their output mapped onto an object so they can subsequently be rendered in the UI without the use of helper libraries, such as ADO.NET or LINQ To SQL. You need to choose which API you want to use before we can be more specific, and ADO.NET and LINQ To SQL are two of the more conventional choices.

Comment: okay lets say i've chosen the LINQ TO SQL as an approach , where should i put the Code you wrote above in the MODEL ?! should i create a LINQ TO SQL classes ?! what are the steps

Comment: What if the query using join statement? Join with customer and another table. Can you still use this approach?

Comment: @sonyvizio You can use any SQL you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use raw SQL queries in ASP.Net MVC the same way you use them anywhere else.

It can be helpful to use idioms like

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    return View(reader.Select(dr => new { Name = dr["Name"], ... }));
```

**EDIT**: It appears that you're asking how to use ADO.Net in general.
Try [this tutorial](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson03.aspx).

Comment: using those methods is not useful for me , the Doctor wants to see something like " Select Dr where name = ".." ;

Comment: @iyad: That goes in the line before this one.

Comment: Then you're asking about ADO.Net; your question has nothing to do with MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use SQL in ASP.NET MVC. I'd consider keeping the SQL code on stored procedures rather than hard-coding the SQL directly in the application code. It's better to maintain and it's a good practice that will probably be looked upon by your instructor.

Comment: Dude, check the title of your question. It starts with "Can I" xD LOL

Answer (score 0):

SQL has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC. ASP.NET MVC is a web framework for building web sites and applications. My suggestion is that you try to abstract as much as possible, the MVC application shouldn't know if you're using SQL (stored procedures), Entity Framework, Linq-to-sql or if you get your data from a web-service.