# asp.net MVC with Linq-to-Sql

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database, linq-to-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use pure SQL in ASP.net MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594233/can-i-use-pure-sql-in-asp-net-mvc)

i asked a similar question in the morning , but didn't get a simple answers " up to my level"

what i'm trying to do is creating a website for my database project using ASP.net MVC
but i need to write SQL queries not LINQ-to-SQL . SO how can i write raw SQL in ASP.net MVC and WHERE ?! in the Model ?! can someone describe the steps in details PLZ simplfy it as much as possible. its my first exposure to the .NET framework

Comment: I'm really sorry but RedFilter's answer is pretty much as simple as it gets.

Comment: People gave you links to the most basic of ADO.NET and "raw sql" tutorials in your duplicate question.

Comment: but they didn't specify where shall i add this code in MVC , shall i create a Model first ?! , DO i have to add LINQ-To-SQL classes ?! guys dont be harsh , is literally my first days in .NET framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would research the Repository pattern. Most examples you'll find pair the Repository pattern with LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework but the pattern is generic. It can work with good old ADO.NET as well.

Scott Hanselman has a good post on extending the Nerd Dinner Repositories to use different data access methods (including classic ADO.NET):

[Scott Hanselman - Extending NerdDinner: Exploring Different Database Options](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExtendingNerdDinnerExploringDifferentDatabaseOptions.aspx)

That way you can structure the rest of your application the same way most examples show you but slip your own Repositories in to the mix to use your chosen data access method.

Comment: This reminds me of the comic/spoof answer where somebody says "how do I add two numbers together in javascript" and somebody replies with "use jquery".  Not sure how this is helpful.  -- Wait... how did you edit this answer without this showing up in the revision log?

Comment: @jfar - I haven't suggested the use of any frameworks. I've simply suggested an architectural decision (which the OP asked for) that will allow him to easily fit classic ADO.NET data access into ASP.NET MVC.